# AWS VPC Routing Issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, routing, openvpn, amazon-vpc

Main issue is i cannot connect to internal ec2 instances or network once the vpn is connected.

So to preface this, I am bad at networking and setting this up, and have read the docs to solve as much as i can. I am looking for more help as i have spent a few days on setting this up and cannot figure out the routing configuration for AWS VPC.

**VPC1**: ipv4 CIDR 172.44.0.0/16

**Subnets(All public):**

- 172.44.1.0/24 [Main subnet] ***(This has the route table below)***
- 172.44.2.0/24
- 172.44.0.0/24

**Route Table:**

- 172.44.0.0/16 **[typo fixed 30 to 44]**   local              Active   No
- 0.0.0.0/0         igw-60f33005   Active   No

  - Virtual Private Gateway - Route Propagation = Yes

**Internet Gateway** setup for **VPC1**

**NAT Gateway:**

- 34.110.17.48 ***(THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL IP)***  172.44.1.117 VPC1 [Main Subnet]subnet-7xxxxx

**EC2 Info:**

Instance:

- Elastic ip: 28.14.134.60 ***(THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL IP)***

SG->

- Custom UDP Rule UDP 1194 0.0.0.0/0
- SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
- All ICMP - IPv4 All N/A 0.0.0.0/0

Server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
server 172.44.0.0 255.255.0.0
push "route 28.14.134.60 255.255.0.0"
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh2048.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 0
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 15 60
comp-lzo adaptive
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
max-clients 100
user nobody
group nogroup
key-direction 0

# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server
push "route 172.44.0.0 255.255.255.255"
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Subnet
# This is probably wrong
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

**ufw:**

- ufw allow 1194/udp
- ufw allow OpenSSH

vim /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
#
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#


# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to wlp11s0 (change to the interface you discovered!)
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.44.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES

...
```

What I need help with is confirming the setup of the gateways and routing. Any tips hints or full corrections would be welcome!!

Comment: Did you disable the [IP source/destination check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck) on the OpenVPN instance inside EC2?  It's documented as being required for NAT Instances, but it is absolutely mandatory for *any* instance that appears as a destination in a VPC route table.

Comment: thanks for the response, and yup i have " Source/Destination Check" disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you mention a VPN connection but your route table is sending traffic 0.0.0.0/0 through the Internet gateway, is that correct?

Is the routing table you have described the correct one? if you are using VPC1: ipv4 CIDR 172.44.0.0/16 then the first entry in the routing table should be:

172.44.0.0/16 Local and not 172.30.0.0/16 Local

Make sure you are looking at the correct route table and make sure it has the local route and the 0.0.0.0/0 IGW route.

Also check that:

1. The NACL linked to the VPC is not blocking your traffic (Inbound and Outbound)
2. There is no OS firewall rules blocking the connection
3. that your Security groups allow the correct traffic (Inbound)

Comment: Dest.       -> Target .       Status   Propogated
0.0.0.0/0 -> igw-6xxxxx  Active   No

Comment: 1. Dest. 0.0.0.0/0      -> Target igw-6xxxxx     -> Status  Active -> Propogated No


2. Typo corrected sorry about that. 

3. That is the VPC Route Table

Comment: VPC NACL Inbound and Outbound are setup as follows=>> 100 -> ALL -> Traffic -> ALL -> ALL -> 0.0.0.0/0 -> ALLOW
......... * -> ALL -> Traffic -> ALL -> ALL -> 0.0.0.0/0 -> DENY

Comment: OS firewall is missing one thing which i will reset and test in a second: /etc/default/ufw ....... <DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT">

Comment: 3. What would be the correct inbound? should i use the NAT Gateway IP? .... I have a VPG, Internet and NAT Gateway setup. The NAT Gateway has a static Elastic IP assigned to it.